# Python: check membership or just use add with set

Tags: python, set, membership

Should I rather check if an element is already present in a set or just use `add()` anyhow?

So better do

```
uniq = set()
_ = [uniq.add('%s %s' % (k,hn)) for hn in v if '%s %s' % (k,hn) not in uniq ]
```

Or better:

```
uniq = set()
_ = [uniq.add('%s %s' % (k,hn)) for hn in v]
```

Is there an advantage choosing one approach over the other?

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension for its side effects. Use a regular `for` loop, avoiding the wasteful creation of a list full of `None`, or use a set comprehension to build the set directly: `uniq = {'%s %s' % (k, hn) for hn in v}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in testing membership if all you are doing is adding values. You are doing extra work the `.add()` method **already does for you**.

You should *never* use a list comprehension for the side effects; you created a list object full of `None` references, then discard it again. A simple `for` loop would have been far more efficient *and* better to understand and maintain.

In this case, you don't need to call `set.add()` in a loop even, just use [`set.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update) with a generator expresion:

```
uniq = set()
uniq.update('%s %s' % (k,hn) for hn in v)
```

where `uniq` is presumably an existing set simplified down to an example. If not, you could use a set comprehension to create your set from scratch, using one line of code:

```
uniq = {'%s %s' % (k,hn) for hn in v}
```